# Non-Profit Forced Donation

Tags: non-profit

A non-profit is holding a fundraising luncheon. They added a "required" donation amount on top of the price of the luncheon. Is this legal?

Comment: It's a "fundraising luncheon" by a private organization; they can make any stipulations they want, short of asking for your first born child. If you don't like the fact that you have to donate, don't eat lunch.

Comment: Where?! Whatever you do might be illegal in one country and legal in another.

Comment: A for-profit is serving lunch. It charges a cover at the door on top of the the price of the lunch. Is this legal?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes it's legal

How would it not be?  It's literally a fundraiser.

Answer (score 1):

### How is it “forced”?

That is, I’m sure you have the choice *not* to attend and therefore not pay either for the meal or the donation.

I think it’s a good idea, most luncheons will include the “profit” in the ticket price so you don’t know how much of your money is going to the food and how much to the cause. Here you do.